# Are oceanic currents influenced by the Coriolis forces?

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents, atlantic, amoc, northatlantic

Hi If you look at the warm water currents in the N Atlantic, you can see how they have an overall eastward movement pattern:

[image]

[Source](https://www.whoi.edu/know-your-ocean/ocean-topics/how-the-ocean-works/ocean-circulation/the-ocean-conveyor/)

If you compare this with the Coriolis forces, which also turn in an easterly direction in the N hemisphere, I wonder if there is a correlation? Or whether the current is only controlled by the continental masses?

[image]

[source](https://studyflix.de/ingenieurwissenschaften/corioliskraft-berechnen-1915)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a major factor in ocean currents is the [geostrophic balance](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780750645522100071#s0120), where Coriolis forces balance pressure gradient forces.  In the northern hemisphere, Coriolis-driven currents flow clockwise around areas of high pressure, such as where the sea surface height is elevated.  This sustains currents like the subtropical north Atlantic gyre.

The Coriolis effect plays into several other processes, such as the [Sverdrup balance](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780750645522100071#s0180), which contributes to western boundary currents, and the more general process of [Ekman transport](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780750645522100071#s0090).  Convergent or divergent Ekman transport, driven by wind stress curl, produces sea surface height anomalies (by "piling up", or moving apart, water at the surface) and thus geostrophic currents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Coriolis effect does impact some of the oceanic currents. One related phenomenon is the *western intensification* that is leading to the *western boudaries currents*.

You can find more on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_current#Western_intensification.

An eastern-flowing current (~ like a jet current) will also form if there is a significant extension of the eastern boundary ( i.e. a continental barrier), and will be located at the same latitude than the land's extension.

If I remember correctly, the Stommels & Arons model as explained in *Ocean Circulation Theory* by Pedlosky explains it well (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03204-6?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=google_books&utm_campaign=3_pier05_buy_print&utm_content=en_08082017).